# Expected value $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-kt/m}\int_0^t e^{ks/m} dB_s\right]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I want to show expected value of below Ito integral goes to zero 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-kt/m}\int_0^t e^{ks/m} dB_s\right]$$ 
where $k, m $  are constant .

Yesterday I found a question like this in math stack exchange  ,But I can't find it now .
I have to solve it , and I don't have clue . I am thankful if someone guide me to prove this . Thanks in advanced .( a clue or address of a page that contain like this question )

Comment: Please no `\dfrac` unless it is necessary (which happens **very** rarely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it a property of the Itô integral that 
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^t f(s,\omega) \, dB(s) \right] = 0,$$ 
for $f$ progressively measurable and such that $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t f(t,\omega)^2 dt] < +\infty$?

Perhaps [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198038/expected-value-of-a-stochastic-integral-expression) is the question you are looking for, but the integral to evaluate in this question has a random variable (i.e., $X$) as a limit of the integral, while in your it seems to be a real number (i.e., $t$) (or better it is not specified).

---

**Edit**

I found also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254572/expectation-of-stopping-time) that could really be what you are looking for!